Store/Load ordering around function call
I need to use atomic_ref to enforce store/load ordering, and since I cannot use it directly in product's API headers (Customers can use C++11) I want to implement it as function of my DLL. But in this case I am not sure compiler is smart enough to not reorder stores/loads around call to my DLL function that does the store that needs to be "released".
So I was trying to google some information about legality of store/load reordering around dll function calls, and the following answer from David Vandevoorde popped up: https://www.quora.com/Since-C-compilers-cannot-know-if-a-function-defined-in-an-external-translation-unit-library-contains-memory-barriers-until-linking-do-they-avoid-reordering-reads-writes-around-such-function-calls
According to his example here https://godbolt.org/z/YGrRcJ compiler is free to reorder stores and loads around function call.
Then I assume the following code is also not enforcing store order in producer, this code looks more like what I want to have in production:
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
 
bool flag = false;
int data = 0;
 
// Imagine functions from the following namespace are implemented in a separate dll
namespace defined_in_another_dll
{
    void flag_ready(bool& b)
    {
        std::atomic_ref<bool>(b).store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    }
    bool is_ready(bool& b)
    {
        return std::atomic_ref<bool>(b).load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
}

void producer()
{
    data = 42;
    defined_in_another_dll::flag_ready(flag); // This call may reorder with data assignment?
}
 
void consumer()
{
    while (!defined_in_another_dll::is_ready(flag));
    assert(data == 42); // May fire because of reordering in producer!
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
}

The question:
Why is it legal for compiler to reorder assignments around function call, while at the same time the following "producer" function is supposed to be legal? Who guarantees that this store is always inlined and optimizer sees compiler barrier? What if this atomic store ends up as a function call? This is confusing.
void producer()
{
    data = 42;
    std::atomic_ref<bool>(flag).store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}


Your Godbolt example only has int r as a local variable in g() whose address doesn't escape the function, so the compiler can prove no other thread could have a reference to it.  Thus its ordering doesn't matter and it can just constant-propagate and keep it in a register.  Same for the bool b function arg: that variable is private to the function.

There might be a valid concern here, though, for example with static or namespace making some non-global variables visible to some code but not the function that's getting a reference to one of them.  Before atomic_ref existed, it would probably be legal to optimize stores around a call to such a function.  Except that GCC and Clang have supported __atomic builtins since C++11 times, and __sync builtins before that, and those have always let functions do atomic ordering-sensitive operations on plain variables, so hopefully optimizers haven't been breaking such code.

Who guarantees that this store is always inlined and optimizer sees compiler barrier? - the default is that compilers can't reorder stuff around a black box (non-inline function call where they can't see the definition).  At least not anything the other function might possibly be able to see.  See How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering? for some detailed discussion and examples of escape analysis and optimizations like you're talking about.  Oh right, any opaque function call could take a mutex lock, that has to work.

compiler can not prove that a variable data not accessed in functions flag_ready/is_ready, so it can not reorder this

@PeterCordes, ah, so this reordering from godbolt example can only apply to local variables which are not address-exposed? Then it makes sense, I somehow forgot that local variables are seen only by a single thread. I guess this can be accepted as answer.

@PeterCordes, could you please elaborate your concern regarding static/namespace, I did not get this part.

GCC and Clang can do escape analysis for static variables from this TU, e.g. optimizing them away if they're only written (not read) in this TU and their address isn't passed to other functions which could make it globally reachable.  The simplest reason why global variable access can't be reordered around a non-inline function call is that the function could read and write any globally-reachable data. But if you can prove it can't see a variable due to static or namespace stuff, you need to find other arguments, like that it might take a mutex and/or call other functions that see vars

In order to conform to the C++ memory model, the compiler has to ensure that any load or store that could be observed by other threads does not get reordered past a memory barrier.  The memory model is indifferent to function call boundaries, so this rule applies whether such a memory barrier is in the current function, or another function which it calls.  All that matters is how the code is sequenced.
As such, the compiler may only reorder such a load or store past a function call if it can prove that the called function does not execute any memory barriers.  This would only be possible if the compiler can actually see the entire source code of the called function at compile time (or link time, in case of LTO).  If the function is opaque, such as is certainly the case for a function defined in an outside DLL, then the compiler must assume that it could contain a memory barrier, and no such reordering can be performed.
Thus, to your question "Who guarantees that this store is always inlined and optimizer sees compiler barrier?" - the burden of proof is the other way around.  It's not that the compiler may reorder unless it sees a memory barrier; rather, it's that it may only reorder if it can verify the absence of a memory barrier, which is only possible if the called function is inlined or otherwise available for interprocedural analysis.

But as mentioned, this only applies to loads or stores that could be observed by other threads.  In the example given by David Vandevoorde, the variable r is local to the caller function, and its address is not passed outside of the caller (indeed, its address is never taken at all).  Thus, there is no way (within the C++ standard) for any other thread to know where this variable is located in memory, so the compiler deduces that no other thread can possibly observe any loads or stores to this object.
At a more mundane level, even in a single-threaded context, the compiler also has to be sure that the called function does not observe the load or store directly.    If f were to try to load from the variable r, it must read the stored value 42, so if that is possible, then the store must be performed before f is called, and must not be reordered with the call.  However, for the same reason as above, here f cannot possibly access r because there is no way for it to know its address.
Therefore, loads or stores to r will not be observed by any code at all, except the code of g itself which the compiler is currently compiling.  It can therefore reorder such loads or stores at will, irrespective of any memory barriers that may or may not be present, so long as g still exhibits the same behavior as if they were performed in program order.  It can even, as in this case, optimize them away entirely; indeed you can see that r itself is optimized away, and the constant value 42 used in its place.

The above discussion does not apply to the code snippet in your question, because there data is global.  Its address is known throughout the program.  Therefore, the compiler must assume that any code not directly visible to the compilation might access it.  It can disregard any accesses from other threads that would constitute a data race, because in that case the behavior is undefined.  But here, the called function might (and indeed does) contain appropriate memory barriers to avoid a data race, so the compiler has to ensure that it works correctly.
Your example code is perfectly safe.
